# Does the accessToken from sfdx expire?

Tags: salesforcedx, accesstoken

I [posted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344301/does-the-authentication-with-sfdx-forceauthdevicelogin-expire) earlier about the authentication with sfdx force:auth:device:login and the answer was "Sessions last indefinitely". So if that is the case, if I retreive the accessToken from sfdx with command sfdx force:org:display, does the accessToken last indefinitely as well? Thanks!

Comment: refreshToken will; accessToken will expire whenever your session settings are set to in the org (30 mins to 24 hours IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

The accessToken will time out after being unused for your "Session Time Out" duration (typically set to 2 hours by default, and can be as high as 24 hours). When the accessToken returns a 403 error on use, sfdx will use the refreshToken to generate a new accessToken. If the accessToken is used in the second half of its lifetime, it will be renewed. For example, if you have a duration of two hours, and you use it at least one hour in, it will then last for two more hours.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again! So if get call sfdx to get the token every time my job runs, I should have a valid token?

Comment: @ChadH. Yes. Did you look at JWT, though? It might be an easier path for your server-based integration.

Comment: Looking at it now. It does look like a better solution. Thanks!